# returning an array with dinamically location in c

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I must return an array `double* b` and compare it with `double* a` inside the function `arrays_equal`. The code doesn't work and test failed. I write here the related codes:

```
double* array_copy(/*IN*/ const double* a, int n) {

   double *b;
   b = xcalloc(n,sizeof(double));

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       *(b + i) = *(a + i);    
       printf("%.2f\n",b[i]);   
       }     
   printf("%.2f\n",b[0]);

   return  b;
}
```

and i write here my test funktion,i must got double* b1 from my array_copy function:

```
void array_copy_test(void) {
    double a1[] = { 1.50, 2.30, 42.42 };
    double* b1 = array_copy(a1, 3);
    test_equal_b(arrays_equal(a1, b1, 3), true);
    free(b1);
```

equal function:

```
bool arrays_equal(/*IN*/ const double* a, /*IN*/ const double* b, int n) {
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<= n; i++){
        if(approx(*(a+i),*(b+i))){

        j++;
       }
    }      

if(n == j){
      return true;
     } else{return false;}

}


void arrays_equal_test(void) {

    double a3[] = { 1.5, 2.3, 42.43 };
    double b3[] = { 1.5, 2.3, 42.42 };
    test_equal_b(arrays_equal(a3, b3, 3), false);


}

bool approx(double a, double b) {
    return fabs(a - b) < 1e-6;
}
```

Can somebody please tell me, where is my problem?

Comment: You have not shown function `test_equal_b`.

Comment: what is the interest of `test_equal_b` while probably `arrays_equal` return true or false ? to compare true and true ? @Navidms how `arrays_equal` is implemented ?

Comment: Please format your code properly:)

Comment: i edited my text and wrote another functions too.

Comment: Your equality test goes out of bounds.

Comment: Not an error, but indexing is less easy to get wrong than dereferencing pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Also not an error, but `if(n == j) {return true;} else {return false;}` —> `return n == j;`.

Comment: regarding: `b = xcalloc(n,sizeof(double));`  Where does the function: `xcalloc()` come from?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!.  please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce your problem and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding: `for(int i = 0; i<= n; i++){`  In C, an array index can be in the range: 0...(number of elements in array -1 ) So the posted code contains undefined behavior because it is accessing beyond the end of the array  Suggest: `for( int i = 0; i<n; i++ ){`  Notice the `<` rather than the `<=`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding;  1) following the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) consistently indent the code: indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: thank you very much.this was my problem,i should write i < n rather than <= .thanks,i lost 5 hours for this mistake

Comment: Don't feel bad, we have all done LOTS of such mistakes.

Comment: it probably doesn't work because in `array_copy()` the value of `n` acts as the number of elements in the array, so a loop like this makes sense: `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)`   However in `arrays_equal()` controling statement of the loop differs (`i <= n`), this means that in the last iteration `*(b+i)` is accessing any double sized value that just happened to be right after your array in your program heap, in other words, garbage value.

Comment: `fabs(a - b) < 1e-6;` is a poor test for "approximately equal".   If is worthless when `a,b` are both very large or small.  A good approximate compare takes into account the relative values of `a,b`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code have some errors. First of all why you wrote `for(int i = 0; i<= n; i++)`? It will iterate `n+1` times in this way. It should be `for(int i = 0; i< n; i++)`.

Then are you expecting your test to return `true`: the third element are quite different  `a3[2] =  42.43`, `b3[2] = 42.42`, the difference is much bigger than 10e-6 so they are not equal.